# How to use fontawesome stacked icons in a Bootstrap media object

Tags: bootstrap-4, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I am trying to use a fontawesome 5 stack in a bootstrap media object:

```
<div class="media">
  <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
  <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-2x fa-fw"></i>
  <i class="fas fa-circle fa-stack-1x fa-inverse fa-fw"></i>
  </span>
  <div class="media-body">
    <h5 class="mt-0">Media heading</h5>
    Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis. Fusce condimentum nunc ac nisi vulputate fringilla. Donec lacinia congue felis in faucibus.
  </div>
</div>
```

However the stacked icon is not vertically aligned, as you can see the inner circle is offset below:

[image: Offset icon]

I have searched and seen a lot of answers to adjust the CSS by `margin:-1px` etc but I would like to know what is actually throwing this offset? There must be a structural way to fix this in the DOM rather than hack at fontawesome CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps but: do power transforms help? https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/power-transforms  The positioning part maybe. (data-fa-transform="up-1")

Also something I tried: use your code in the fontawesome site, page: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/stacking-icons

And the icons are perfectly aligned there:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I inserted your exact html code into the site with inspector *
Maybe you can compare the css this way with your installation.

Comment: Thanks but the issue is in the media wrapper; unfortunately your example doesn't replicate this.

Comment: Ye hard to say for me maybe then :(  Maybe it is line-height or something, or font-size?